# Why isn't this image taking up more of the screen?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I've been at this for hours and I can't make the image fill more of the screen. Width is set to auto, yet my images are still windowboxing. Max height is set to 90vh to leave room for title and buttons later, but this is barely even half the screen height. I'm at a loss here. Just want a lightbox where image of ambiguous size scales to fill either horizonal edge or vertical edge.

**Css**

```
.myLightbox{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.myLightboxImage{
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

**JSX**

```
<div className={"myLightbox"}>
   <div>
       <button style={{position: "absolute", top: "25px", right: "25px"}}onClick={() => imgAction()}>X</button>
       <img src={data.img.url} className={"myLightboxImage"}/>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't you want `height: 90vh` on the image instead of `max-height`?

Comment: that would cause unwanted aspect ratio stretching on images in landscape orientation and doesn't really solve the issue.

Comment: Set height and width to 100% and use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: didn't do anything, If I switch the lightbox display to block it works, but I lose the vertical centering.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is smaller than viewport, then it works as expected. If you want to make it bigger, then you have to give it larger dimensions, for example, set `width:100%;height:auto;`. Or just use scripts like Fancybox5 which solves it for you and also gives you tons of customization options.